# Unity: Why GetRootGameObjects() in Unity SceneManager always return empty array if scene was Additivly preloaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void FindSceneHandler(int sceneToLoad)
{
    var scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(SceneManager.sceneCount - 1);
    var sceneOtherApproach = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(sceneToLoad);

    var sceneObjs = scene.GetRootGameObjects();
    print(sceneObjs.Length); // 0

    sceneObjs = sceneOtherApproach.GetRootGameObjects();
    print(sceneObjs.Length); // 0
}
```

This code works fine when I load scene through script and wait until it loads before calling this method. But when I load same scene additive through Unity Editor it always results in empty array.

Actually, problem is bit bigger than that. My main scene depends on data from another one, so I'm trying to loop through new scene's objects to get needed references. Maybe there's another way of getting cross scene data?

Comment: Have you checked if the scene is even valid? See [`SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex.html) `This method will return a valid Scene if a Scene has been added to the build settings at the given build index AND the Scene is loaded. If it has not been loaded yet the SceneManager cannot return a valid Scene.` => your scene is most probably not landed yet => not valid => no root gameObjects

Comment: Yeah, problem was that I needed these objects for scripts to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed the problem. It seems that "Awake()" is called before scenes are fully loaded. I switched it to "Start()" and now everything works perfectly.

Comment: Have in mind though that even if [Multi Scene Editing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html) is supported within the Editor itself even for entering Play mode this is not the case for an actual Build of your application where you will always start with a single scene and have to load other scenes via script!

Comment: Yeah. It was mainly for testing purposes and better understanding of an engine.

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't  `LoadAsync` in `Awake`.

Comment: @Seideun Out of curiosity, can you give a short explanation or link why you should not LoadAsync in Awake?